# How do I order subgraph clusters when using dot?

Tags: graphviz, dot

I have a dot file in which I create subgraph clusters which I want to appear in a specific order, let's say I have this:

```
digraph G {
    splines=true;
    sep="+25,25";
    overlap=scalexy;
    nodesep=0.6;
    subgraph cluster_2 {
        label="ADD_MORE_PROBLEMS";
        subgraph cluster_3 {
            label="pattern";
            N1 [label="problem"];
        }
        subgraph cluster_4 {
            label="replacement";
            N2 [label="problem"];
            N3 [label="problem"];
        }
    }
}
```

Which creates:

[image: output from dot]

How do I ensure that "pattern" appears to the left of "replacement" (I may have an arbitrary number of subgraphs).

Comment: Just a clarification, in the file there are several top level clusters and those do in fact appear left to right as expected.

Comment: reversing the order of your internal clusters seems to give the figure you want. More generally, it seems that subgraphs appear first at the right to the left as the appear in the code.

Comment: Thanks. Eventually I also wanted to have nested subgraphs and things started getting out of control. I ended up rendering each subgraph and then compositing the individual images in the right order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clusters are one of the odd cases where simply the ordering in the code makes most (if not quite all) of the difference. If we simply reorder your code like this:

```
digraph G {
    splines=true;
    sep="+25,25";
    overlap=scalexy;
    nodesep=0.6;
    subgraph cluster_2 {
        label="ADD_MORE_PROBLEMS";
        subgraph cluster_4 {
            label="replacement";
            N2 [label="problem"];
            N3 [label="problem"];
        }
        subgraph cluster_3 {
            label="pattern";
            N1 [label="problem"];
        }
    }
}
```

that makes all the difference.[image: The "ADD_MORE_PROBLEMS" cluster contains both the "pattern" cluster and the "replacement" cluster. The "pattern" cluster is to the left of the "replacement" cluster. The "pattern" cluster contains a single node, labeled 'problem'. The "replacement" cluster contains two nodes, both labeled 'problem'.]

Now, that can fail, in which case setting up invisible edges is one of the more common solutions.

Answer (score 4):

I can't give and answer, but can provide some clarification. The usual approach to force layout is to introduce hidden edges. In this case, it does not work.

Without the nested clusters, you can use `rank=same` to force connected edges onto the same level. Then, an invisible edge `N1 -> N2 [style = invis]` would force the nodes into the correct ordering.

However, constraining nodes with rank breaks the cluster membership and prevents the scheme from working.

The modified graph shows the result. There may not be a general solution.

```
digraph G {
    splines=true;
    sep="+25,25";
    overlap=scalexy;
    nodesep=0.6;
    subgraph cluster_2 {
        label="ADD_MORE_PROBLEMS";
        subgraph cluster_3 {
            label="pattern";
            N1 [label="problem 1"];
        }
        subgraph cluster_4 {
            label="replacement";
            N2 [label="problem 2"];
            N3 [label="problem 3"];
        }
        // Introduce hidden edge (shown dashed)
        N1 -> N2 [style = dashed];
        // Force nodes to remain at same rank
        { rank = same; N1; N2; }
    }
}
```

[image: Constrained luster ordering]